# PubSub EventBus in Java (comet-style)

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, esb, comet, event-bus

I am trying to build a very simply event bus, where both subscriptions and publications are made in Java applications.

However, the bus needs to be deployed on server side, while multiple subscribers and publishers can interact with it, from different locations.

So for example, [*simpleeventbus*](http://code.google.com/p/simpleeventbus/) and [*EventBus*](http://eventbus.org/) are good but only when working with a single JVM.

I’ve been thinking about a [*Comet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))-like framework, but one where I could do the publications/subscriptions directly within Java. Do such frameworks or libraries exist?

Or what other suggestion would there be for this?

Comment: Have you considered Mule ESB or Fuse as a ready-to-use products? Now, you said you wanted to build one, so my suggestion is to look at ActiveMQ as a foundation. It has PubSub support via JMS or native ActiveMQ protocols, so building an ESB may be a simpler task, if that's the route you want to take.

Comment: If you use Spring you can easily embed ActiveMQ in your application context as a bean.

Comment: If you need event bus for only one application instance you can look into my project https://github.com/javaplugs/minibus that implements such functionality for java 8

Comment: The sister site [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this kind of Question.

Answer (score 0):

check Oracle complex event processing (CEP). There is an example in CEP documentation , how to integrated with Bayeux protocol by the Dojo Foundation.